# plantilla twig header y footer siempre visible sin usar {% block [...] %}

Tags: symfony, template, twig, symfony4

estoy haciendo una web para mi y tengo una duda sobre como usar las plantillas. Es decir, ahora mismo utilizo `{% block [...] %}` para añadir en las páginas mi header y footer. 
Pero me gustaría hacer que tanto header como footer siempre estén presentes en la página sin tener que invocarlos en cada página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Poner en la plantilla base el contenido del header y el footer sin meterlo dentro de ninguna etiqueta block. Con esto siempre te saldrá sin tener que invocarlo, el problema es que tampoco lo podrás quitar en ninguna plantilla que herede de esa. Si no lo vas a quitar nunca esta puede ser la mejor opción.
2. Poner en la plantilla base el contenido de header y footer dentro de etiquetas block pero no invocar esos bloques desde la plantilla hija. De esta forma siempre saldrán, pero si, además en una plantilla hija quieres que no aparezca nada en alguno de los bloques lo invocas en vacío. Y si quieres que aparezcan pero con otro contenido los invocas con ese contenido que entonces sustituirá al de la plantilla base.

Te pongo los dos ejemplos para que te quede más claro:

```html
{# Caso 1 - Plantilla base: base.html.twig #}
<html>
  <head>
  ...
  </head>
 <body>
  <nav>
    <li>Inicio</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Acerca de</li>
  <nav>
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
  <footer>
   ...
  </footer>
</body>
</html>

{# Plantilla hija #}
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Mi blog</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum, lo otro y el de la moto</p>
{% endblock %}
```

```html
    {# Caso 2 - Plantilla base: base.html.twig #}
    <html>
      <head>
      ...
      </head>
      <body>
      {% block header %}
       <nav>
         <li>Inicio</li>
         <li>Blog</li>
         <li>Acerca de</li>
       <nav>
      {% endblock %}
     
     {% block content %}
     {% endblock %}
     
     {% block footer %}
      <footer>
       ...
      </footer>
     {% endblock %}

    </body>
    </html>


    {# Plantilla hija - Como ves aquí todo es igual#}
    {% extends "base.html.twig" %}
    {% block content %}
    <h1>Mi blog</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, lo otro y el de la moto</p>
    {% endblock %}
```